# Getting started with vstest.console.exe System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I have a simple executable project and a Unit Test project all in the same solution in Visual Studio 2013.  All my unit tests work fine in Visual Studio. I wanted to play* with the console app vstest.console.exe but am having a hard time getting going. I suspect I'm missing something very simple.  I tried going to the directory where the actual .exe is and ran:

> C:\BuildTest\Frame\Frame\obj\Debug>vstest.console.exe
>   C:\BuildTest\Frame\FrameUnitTests\obj\Debug\FrameUnitTests.dll
>   /Platform:x64 /Tests:ConstructorTest

and I got the error:

Starting test discovery, please wait...
Failed   ConstructorTest
Error Message:
   Test method FrameUnitTests.MainWindowPresenterTests.ConstructorTest threw
exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Frame, Vers ion=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one
>   of its dependencies. T he system cannot find the file specified.WRN:
>   Assembly binding logging is turned  OFF.

I also tried running it from the actual directory where the unit test dll is:

C:\BuildTest\Frame\FrameUnitTests\obj\Debug>
and got the same results.

The error indicates that I need to somehow tell vstest.console where to find the main assembly that is being tested.  How do I do this?  Can someone point me to an example?

I'm interested in playing with vstest.console.exe for the following reason:  I would like to get a printout of all my unit tests (about 80 of them) for use in documentation.  I can't find a good way to do this.  It occurred to me that vstest.console might be helpful for this.  If there is another way to get a list of all my tests, I'd like to know.  Admittedly, I could have simply typed every test title into MSWord in the time I've worked on this, but I'm a glutton for punishment and it might be nice to know how to use vstest.

I tried John Koerner's suggestion (see his answer) to get a list of tests and got the following results which might be a hint as to what I have going wrong:

C:\BuildTest\Frame\FrameUnitTests\obj\Debug>vstest.console.exe /ListTests:
FrameUnitTests.dll
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.21005.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework Framework45 and platform X86. Follo
wing DLL(s) will not be part of run:
ACMFrameUnitTests.dll is built for Framework Framework45 and Platform X64.
 Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more detail
s on managing these settings.
Error: None of the provided test containers match the Platform Architecture and
.Net Framework settings for the test run.  Platform: X86   .Net Framework: Frame
work45.  Go to http://go.microsoft.com/?link for more details on managing these
settings.

Comment: The error you are getting is an assembly loading problem, your best bet is to enable fusion logs to help you understand what it is looking for exactly (it could be a reference of Frame that is missing).  See this article on enabling fusion logs: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: I will look at the article. Thanks!  I also strongly suspect that I am missing a reference to Frame.  There must be some way to add it.  Recall, all works fine in Visual Studio.  What I am doing must be extremely common (just one .exe. project and one UnitTest project) and I suspect there is an example somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need a list of tests, you can simply run the following command:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\ide\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /ListTests:UnitTests.dll

Comment: Hmm.  Tried that.  Didn't work but perhaps it's a clue.  I added results as edit to my question.  I am interested in getting vstest.console working for its own sake.